# CSS & JS - Excel like column resize of table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table that has multiple columns. I want to add the column resize functionality just like that of the excel file tables. On resize, only the column width should increase instead of the width of the next columns so that there is a scroll below the table.

I even tried using this plugin but can't achieve what I really need.
Plugin Demo: http://dobtco.github.io/jquery-resizable-columns/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin instead :
https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable

This has the functionality you are looking for
chekout their demo with **resizeMode: 'overflow'**
http://bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples